# Kubernetes pvc request and Physical storage

Tags: kubernetes

I use NFS in kubernetes cluster.

Now, I create 5 PVCs in with the same StorageClass **successfully**, and each PVC claims uses 100G. so a total of 500G.

Q: Why can I create 5 PVCs?

NFS provides 300G physical storage actually.

Q: What happens if a PVC actually occupies more than its declared request(100G<pvc<300G)?

Comment: what is response of the command `kubectl get pvc`?

Comment: Which nfs provisioner are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Why can I create 5 PVCs?

You might want to check  the [PVs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) allocated (Persistent Volumes). You can create a PVC but it doesn't mean that the PV will get allocated. A PVC is a Persistent Volume **Claim** but it doesn't mean you always get it.

```sh
kubectl get pv --all-namespaces
```

> Q: What happens if a PVC actually occupies more than its declared request(100G<pvc<300G)?

If the combined PVs exceed 300G well you won't be able to store passed that in your case.

If for some reason you have PVs that exceed your total space, you might actually have a bug (❓)

✌️

Comment: For Q1,i can get 5 PVs successfully. 
For question 2,From the test results,The PVC statement of zk requires 10G. But check the partition information in the container, the actual NFS volume has occupied 14G, but it can still work normally. (Because the total physical storage capacity of NFS is 80G).

Answer (score 0):

When you run create command its not yet completed is like job accepted, then k8s will try to match your claim with available PersistentVolume.

After you create pvc run

`kubectl get pvc`

ANd make sure that status is **bound**, if its not then k8s cant find a storage for your claim

Regartding second question. If you mount that PVC to pod then pod wont be able to write more than you allocated

Comment: For question 2,From the test results,The PVC statement of zk requires 10G. But check the partition information in the container, the actual NFS volume has occupied 14G, but it can still work normally. (Because the total physical storage capacity of NFS is 80G).